# how to get schema for OpenShift/K8s resources, e.g. How to get schema definition for deployment config or pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

When I'm creating resources for OpenShift/K8s, I might be out of coverage area. I'd like to get schema definition being offline.

How I can get from command line a schema for a kind. For example I would like to get a generic schema for Deployment, DeploymentConfig, Pod  or a Secret.
Is there a way to get schema without using google? Ideally if I could get some documentation description for it.

Comment: Have you tried running `oc explain --recursive Deployment`? You still need to be connected when you generate it, so you would need to save it to a file for later reference. Maybe also get down and read the free eBook at https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/ which mentions this command and lots of other stuff as well.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton sorry for the late response. At the time I was asking this question I was not familiar, later I asked colleague and he showed me. It is the best thing I wanted. It fully answers my question.

Comment: Please consider posting it as an answer so the rest of the community could benefit from your info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting @Graham Dumpleton comment as a community wiki answer basing on the response from OP saying that it solved his/her problem:

> Have you tried running `oc explain --recursive Deployment`? You still
>   need to be connected when you generate it, so you would need to save
>   it to a file for later reference. Maybe also get down and read the
>   free eBook at openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift which mentions this
>   command and lots of other stuff as well. – Graham Dumpleton